# Is there a way to implement Item(s) in a Canvas instead of in a Form?

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I am trying to make a game application and create a menu of strings that can be selected easily by the user by just clicking the arrow keys on their devices.

I already know how I could do it the longway by identifying the user's actions using KeyPressed(). But I just wanted to know if such implementation of Item class and subclasses exist for a Canvas?

Answer (score 1):

Not for standard JavaME classes, but there are plenty of GUI libraries around you could use. For example, LWUIT, which is quite popular.
http://lwuit.java.net/